# C#, turn html to valid html e-mail

Tags: c#, .net, ruby, ironruby

I want to turn an html page that can easily be edited on the net to a valid html e-mail (inline styles, absolute links etc).

I have found this project [premailer](https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer/), it changes your html to work well in as much e-mail clients as possible.  I want to know if a .NET equivalent exists or if it could be possible to run this project in IronRuby for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Ruby code, so I would expect that it would run in IronRuby.  Did you try it and run into problems?

Comment: When I try to do:

igem install premailer, I get the following error:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.